# How to set environment variables in a docker container after it starts

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I need to set some environment variables in a docker container after it starts. When the docker starts env X gets value, then I want to set env Y with a value which is the first part of the value X with this command:
Y=$(echo $X | cut -d'@' -f 1)

Is there any way to do this?

I tried ENTRYPOINT and CMD in the Dockerfile, but it doesn't work.
The docker will be deployed on a Kubernetes cluster, and I also tried to set them in the config.yaml file but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Perhaps that docker image has a script that runs on startup. Is this a public image?

Comment: You can use an `ENTRYPOINT ["do_something.sh"]` in the Docker image and execute `Y=$(echo $X | cut -d'@' -f 1)` in the `do_something.sh` bash script ?

Comment: I did it with CMD, I don't know what are the differences of CMD and ENTRYPOINT.  I realized that I need to use "source" so the command will be executed in the current shell environment. So I added CMD["source ./script.sh"] but it doesn't work. I had to execute the source manually inside the docker image but I don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track that you would have to handle this by either CMD or ENTRYPOINT, because you want it to be dynamic and derived from existing data. The specifics would depend on your container and use case though.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm on the right track, however the problem still exists. :D Apparently, I need to use "source ./script.sh" so the commands will be executed on the current shell environment, but  CMD["source ./script.sh"] doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed, you need to make your cmd a bash script which sets the env var and then runs your original command.

Comment: I think the problem is that when my script is executed the env X still has no value. How can I wait until X gets value?

Comment: If you set it correctly, it would be present as soon as your container runs. Sounds like maybe you have a different problem?

Comment: I think I found the problem, the base image I'm using has already an entrypoint and as I know we can't have multiple entrypoints in docker. I don't know what should I do.

Comment: You probably want to use a cmd then.

Comment: I built the image from scratch and execute my script inside the script that was executed using entrypoint and cmd, but still is not executed :|

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ENV command in your dockerfile like below:

```
ENV PORT 8080
```

Source and more info - https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-time-env-values/

Comment: "build-time" is pertinent. That's *before* it starts.

Comment: I need to set those env variables after the container starts, so ENV is not the solution. Thanks by the way.